# Returning historical yield rates for Mortgage Backed Securities in a Bloomberg Terminal?

Tags: bloomberg, mbs

Forgive me if this isn't the right place, and direct me to the correct place to post.

I've been trying to figure out how to get the yield rates for Mortgage Backed Securities (MBS's) in the United States dating back the last 30 years or so. I've been unable to do so.

The closest I have gotten is the command string `MTGEFNCL F10<GO>` to get there. But that's for the historical current coupon (which I understand to be a different thing).

Is there a command or a way to call the data for the yield rates?

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: I mean, yes I did, but that just told me to email them. The reason I came on here wasn't to be told to ask someone else.